# How to add "multiple intervals" to a .Net Chart?

Tags: c#, .net, charts

I have a set of numbers from 437 to 2500 (this is just an example; theoretically the set can start from 0) that I need to plot on a chart.

These are the settings:

```
chartArea.AxisX.Interval = 500;
chartArea.AxisX.Minimum = 437;
chartArea.AxisX.Maximum = 2500;
```

And this is the result:
[image: plot]

The issue is the intervals (major grid and labels) on the X axis. I need it to start from 437 (which it does), but after that the intervals should be rounded (which they aren't).
These are the desired intervals: 437, 1000, 1500, 2000, 2500.

Comment: The automatic Intervals will always be at constant distances. You could offset their start though.. Example : `chartArea.AxisX.IntervalOffset = 63;`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @TaW. This is correct, but I would loose the 437 label (which I need) and have the 500 interval & label (which I don't need). Maybe another set X example could be numbers from 1 to 100 and the expected intervals & labels would be [1, 10, 20, ..., 100].

Comment: If you want to cheat on the chart you need to use CustomLabels. Q&D example: `CustomLabel cl = new CustomLabel(s.Points[i].XValue - 250, s.Points[i].XValue + 250,
    i == 0 ? s.Points[i].XValue + "" : ((i + 1) * 500) + "", 0, LabelMarkStyle.None);
              
ax.CustomLabels.Add(cl);`. This goes into a loop over i which adds the points, right after each point is added. IYou can also put it into a separate loop that runs later.